Next js Image component not working properly
I am using next Image component in one of my project it is showing wrong image, and when I add unoptimised true then it is showing correct image.
Can anyone help me how to make image optimized and show correctly in Image component?
I tried adding cache headers and also tried adding minimumTTL, still the issue remain same.
"use Client";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

export default function BlurImage({
  imageUrl,
  alt,
  height,
  width,
  hasPriority,
  isUnoptimize,
  srcSet,
}) {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView({
    triggerOnce: true,
    threshold: 0.5,
  });
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="img-wrapper">
      {srcSet ? (
        <picture>
          <source media="(max-width:767px)" srcSet={srcSet} />
          <Image
            src={imageUrl}
            alt={alt}
            height={height}
            width={width}
            sizes="100vw"
            quality={100}
            style={{
              opacity: inView ? 1 : 0,
              width: "100%",
              height: "auto",
              maxWidth: "60px!important",
            }}
            {...(hasPriority ? { priority: true } : {})}
            unoptimized={isUnoptimize ? true : false}
          />
        </picture>
      ) : (
        <Image
          src={imageUrl}
          alt={alt}
          height={height}
          width={width}
          sizes="100vw"
          quality={100}
          style={{
            opacity: inView ? 1 : 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: "auto",
          }}
          {...(hasPriority ? { priority: true } : {})}
          unoptimized={isUnoptimize ? true : false}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


show us the code

Show us the code, and the image please

I have added my image component code

add a question mark at then end of url and try again. if it worked delete .next folder and start dev again. also delete the question mark.

Please share the value in imageUrl. Next.js Image component doesn't work well with externally fetched images e.g. https://image.com/blah-blah-blah.jpeg on production. Make sure it's a local image stored in your project folder, otherwise use the img element.

What if we want to use images from Amazon S3 bucket
